# Pause a video for 3 seconds, then resume playing video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

There is a link at the top left that will pause this video.  (line 22-24)
http://codepen.io/datanity/pen/GnqhF

I was hoping there would be a way to pause the video for only 3 seconds after pressing this button, at which point the video would resume playing.

In this case, it would be important not to relocate the content in lines 22-24 to a different part of the code.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need something like this:

```
 $('button').on('click',function(){
    audio.pause();
    setTimeout(function () {
      audio.play();
    }, 3 * 1000); // 3 seconds
  });
```